# Flask download zip file: Failed - No file

Tags: html, flask

I'm currently designing a Flask website and I want to add some download links to it. After doing some research, I found out that adding download links can be done this way:

```
<a href="pathToDownloadFile" download>
    <p> Click to download! </p>
</a>
```

But when I click on the "Click to download!" hyperlink, the downloaded file doesn't show in my downloads folder. Instead, on my chrome browser, it indicates: `Failed - No file` below the download name.

[image: example]

Basically, chrome didn't successfully download the file to my computer. After revising my path structure, nothing seemed wrong.

Here is my full HTML code for the download page:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Clicker Game Modes</title>
    <h1>Clicker Game Modes:</h1>
    <button style="margin-top: -60; position: absolute" onclick="location.href = '/'" type="submit">Back</button>
    <style>
        h1 {
            color: red;
            font-family: Cursive;
            margin-left: 410;
        }

        p, a {
            color: black;
            font-family: Verdena, sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        button {
            margin-left: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 15px 25px;
            font-size: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: none;
            color: #000000;
            background-color: lime;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: green;
        }

        button:active {
            background-color: #406341;
            box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
            transform: translateY(4px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body> <br> <br>
    <p style="font-size:30px; font-family: Monospace;">Money earning:</p>
    <a style="color: #5539CC;" href="downloads/Money_Earning_Mode.zip" download>
        <p style="color: #5539CC;">Download: <b>Money Earning</b> clicker game</p>
    </a>


</body>
```

And here is my path structure:

[image: example2]

Note that the file I'm working on is `modes.html`.

How can I successfully download the `.zip` folder located in my downloads folder?

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-download-files-in-flask

Comment: Is there a way to fix the current problem instead of using a new way? I'm confident that following the instructions at educative.io/edpresso/how-to-download-files-in-flask will get my file downloaded, but I'd rather only use HTML code to solve the problem.

Comment: What does your flask log say?

Comment: Flask log says: "GET /downloads/Money_Earning_Mode.zip HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could maybe work if you set to `download` attribute the filename? This way:

```
<a href="pathToDownloadFile" download="filename.zip"> ... </a>
```